# Why on earth was this flag declined?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged [this](https://serverfault.com/a/339904/10472) as Not an Answer. Apologies to Sven, but it's just plain not an answer. It's a comment asking for clarification and offering general advice. I asked for a sanity check after the decline in Comms Room and some of the other regular flaggers agree with me that it belongs as a comment (which is why I flagged it as NAA in the first place).

Can someone explain to me what it is I missed that caused this flag to be declined and ding me for -10 fw?

According to the moderator [blog](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/) moderators are supposed to accept all flags in good faith. It's pretty clear to both me and other regular flaggers that there's at least one mod that isn't taking that to heart. What gives?

Comment: There has definitely been someone messing with the regular flaggers as I have gotten a few declined on questions that have either been closed or migrated and I know I'm not the only one.

Comment: I've had the same problem. I think Choppers thoughts about on this subject are pretty good, so I'm just going to steal them: "When I see where you are coming from, I'll accept it, even if I don't agree/act upon it".

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you that it isn't an answer :) To my probably unnecessary defense, this post started its life as a list of potential techniques the OP might look up and I already had written about DRBD, clustered file systems, heartbeat and round robin DNS but something came up and I decided to quickly edit out the middle part and hit send instead of looking up links and adding more info.

Can't tell why the flag wasn't denied, though but why worrying about flag weight?

I just moved this over as a comment, BTW.

Comment: `but why worrying about flag weight?` - I worry about flag weight because it's part of the site, much like rep just less visible. It will take about 20 successful flags just to get back to where I was before this decline, because it is non-linear after 500fw. This isn't an isolated incident, many active flaggers in Comms have noted that there is a mystery mod that is declining stuff that clearly shouldn't be declined.

Comment: P.S. Thanks for being a good sport. I wasn't calling you out as much as I was looking for an explanation about the inconsistent flag responses that we seem to be getting. :)

Answer (score 2):

I can see where someone would disagree, that the "comment" is helpful enough, and pointing the Questioner in the right direction enough, to be left as an Answer.

That said, the Answer *doesn't actually answer the question*... I agree with the NAA flag.

In the end, [Mods are supposed to be taking flags in good faith](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/), as this one should have been.